# Missing FacebookSignedRequest.Dictionary in 4.2.1

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Hi
I have downloaded 4.2.1 and found that the property Dictionary is no longer available in class FacebookSignedRequest.  Is there any preferred way to get the JSON object from the return of Facebook registration plugin?
Cheers
Edwin

Answer (score 1):

We removed the dictionary because we now serialize the entire object. You can access the full set of properties provided by the signed request on the FacebookSignedRequest object. Did you have a specific need for the dictionary that this doesn't solve?

Comment: I am trying to use the Facebook Registration Plugin where to ask users entering emails and other information.  I thought the registration data can be found in the dictionary of FacebookSignedRequest object. If it is now removed, then can you kindly advise how to obtain this data from the FacebookSignedRequest object.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at my fork - I've updated the code to handle registration requests. http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/Forks/cvallance/FBSDKRegisterPluginSupport